# On first load, user sees glimpse of end of animation before animation starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a simple page that involves some animations. The first time the page is loaded, the user sees the end result of the animations for a split second, before going to the start of the animations. The animation sequence is of a blank screen, with words and sentences fading into or sliding into view. I am using the animation.css javascript library.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#pineappleCheesecake').addClass('animated fadeIn');

$('h1').addClass('animated rubberBand');

$('p').addClass('animated bounceInUp')

$('ul').addClass('animated lightSpeedIn');

});
```

I have tried using this instead of document ready

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // ...
});
```

But this did not work. I then tried taking the document.ready out completely, but I had the same results.

I could try having the page load with a black div covering the screen, which I would remove at the beginning of the animation, but it seems like a hackish way of doing it, and I suspect there's a simpler, cleaner, better way of removing the unintended glimpse of the end result. Please help.

Comment: Your `ready` hooks will load after the page is rendered.  So, you're probably seeing the "final result" for a split second before JavaScript can initialize the animated elements to their starting state.  Try disabling the script altogether and see if it stays on the "end result".

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery $(document).ready(function() {
   ... 
}); ? If so, show the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, it stays on the end result when script is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all of the CSS values to their 'default' before the javascript runs. This may fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought everyone would assume I was initializing my code with document.ready, as I mentioned it in my question as something I took out. Yes, I was using document.ready.

Comment: Nope. Same result. I'm trying to get the animation's starting point earlier. document ready and setTimeout only delay the animation.

Comment: As I said in my question, I was aware I could do that, but was looking to see if there was a more direct, less hackish solution.

Comment: Ok... This will cover the animation

Comment: Nope. Does not work. Same result. The glimpse is probably happening before the javascript runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my problem. Although it is not the clean answer I was looking for, and I still suspect there's a more direct solution out there, I made this solution as simple as possible.

In the html, I surrounded everything in the body in a div bracket.

```
<div id="coverDiv">
...
</div>
```

In the CSS, I set it's properties to this.

```
#coverDiv {
    background: black;
    display: none;
}
```

In the javascript, I began the animation by displaying the coverDiv.

```
$("#coverDiv").css("display", "inline");
```

In actuality, the coverDiv doesn't cover, so much as it contains, and is revealed at the beginning of the animation.

Thanks to DripDrop for steering me towards this solution.